# Adding the reference of a local copy of Jquery into Xcode project

Tags: jquery, ios, objective-c, xcode, webview

I've been having some troubles while working with a local html file in a webview in my project, at first we could not load the jquery file from its CDN, then we read somewhere it was better to use it locally then we managed to set the file (jquery.js) in the copy bundle. Now our question is how do we reference the jquery.js inside the .html which is also locally loaded, we use the script tag like this and is not working.

```
<script src="jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```

We also have tried this method when made sure UIWebView has finished loading...

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"jquery-1.10.1.min" ofType:@"js" inDirectory:@""];
NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSString *jsString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithData:fileData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
```

I'd like to know what step I am missing, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran into this. It appears that, by default, JS files get added to the "Compile Sources" build phase. Delete it from this phase and add it to the "Copy Bundle Resources" phase.